# How to have a zigzag border with a backgroundcolor and a different contour color?

Tags: html, css, border

I have a container with text. The container should have a background color (rgba(242,156,51,0.15) and a zigzag border with another color, like orange for exmaple. Is this possible?

See the image below how I want it

[image]

This is what I have

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 8px 32px 8px;
  background: #dddccf;
}

.container:after {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffffff 16px, transparent 0), linear-gradient(45deg, #ffffff 16px, transparent 0);
  background-position: left-bottom;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 32px 32px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;
  transform: rotate(180deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Lorem Ipsum
</div>
```

Comment: Depends - mostly on the parts you were largely unspecific on, such as whether this needs to work in a “transparent” fashion, or with solid backgrounds only. Plus, “is it possible” questions aren’t that welcome here to begin with - please go read [ask] in that regard.

Comment: do you need this border to be on all 4 sides?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-border-20021107/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution is to combine SVG and multiple background. The idea is to create the top shape using SVG and repeat it:

```css
.container {
  width:400px;
  margin:50px;
  height:200px;
  background:
  url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='22 -5 20 15' height='20' width='20'><path stroke='red' fill='orange' stroke-width='2' d='M16 16 L48 16 L32 0 Z' /></svg>")0 0/20px 20px repeat-x,
  linear-gradient(orange,orange)0 20px/100% 100% no-repeat;
}

body {
 background:linear-gradient(to right, pink,yellow);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

And if you want it in all the sides you can try this:

```css
.container {
  width:400px;
  margin:50px;
  height:200px;
  background:
  url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg style='transform:rotate(180deg)' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='22 -5 20 15' height='20' width='20'><path  stroke='red' fill='orange' stroke-width='2' d='M16 16 L48 16 L32 0 Z' /></svg>")0 100%/20px 20px repeat-x,
  url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='22 -5 20 15' height='20' width='20'><path stroke='red' fill='orange' stroke-width='2' d='M16 16 L48 16 L32 0 Z' /></svg>")20px 0/20px 20px repeat-x,
  linear-gradient(orange,orange)0 20px/100% calc(100% - 40px) no-repeat;
  position:relative;
}
.container:after {
   content:'';
   position:absolute;
   top:20px;
   bottom:20px;
   width:20px;
   right:-20px;
   background:
  url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg style='transform:rotate(90deg)' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='22 -5 20 15' height='20' width='20'><path  stroke='red' fill='orange' stroke-width='2' d='M16 16 L48 16 L32 0 Z' /></svg>")0 0/20px 20px repeat-y;
}
.container:before {
   content:'';
   position:absolute;
   top:20px;
   bottom:20px;
   width:20px;
   left:-20px;
   background:
  url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg style='transform:rotate(270deg)' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='22 -5 20 15' height='20' width='20'><path  stroke='red' fill='orange' stroke-width='2' d='M16 16 L48 16 L32 0 Z' /></svg>")0 0/20px 20px repeat-y;
}

body {
 background:linear-gradient(to right, pink,yellow);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Comment: this comes a bit late, but how to make the zigzags more flat (height) just like in the image I added?

Comment: You can edit the shape by tweaking the SVG Path attribute d to your needs following the documentation here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d